# Не могу подключить базу данных через ODBC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, fastreport

Такая проблема пытаясь подключить базу данных Access к visual studio, а после задать ее в данных отчета в FastReport, но выскакивает исключение ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Report report1 = new Report();
        report1.RegisterData(database2DataSet1,"NortWind");
        report1.Load("Безымянный2.frx");
        report1.Show();
    }
```

Подскажите как все же решить эту проблему пытался уже и через реестр сделать, и через ODBC 32-битную ничего не помогло. Исключение появляется на report1.Show(). ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Создание экземпляра соединения
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=Data\\People.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

        return new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

Весь проект [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsAccessDB)

Comment: Не сработало, все также выдает ошибку.